# pyspark sqlfunction expr function not working as expected?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

pyspark sqlfunction expr not working as expected.

my test1.txt contains

```
101|10|4
101|12|1
101|13|3
101|14|2
```

my test2.txt contains

```
101|10|4
101|11|1
101|13|3
101|14|2
```

I have created two dataframes using above data like below code.

```
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("C://Users//cravi//Desktop//test1.txt").map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:3]),["cid","pid","pr"])
    df4 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("C://Users//cravi//Desktop//test2.txt").map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:3]),["cid","pid","p"])
    df5=df4.withColumnRenamed("p", "p")\
            .join(df3.withColumnRenamed("pr", "Pr")\
            , ["cid", "pid"], "outer")\
            .na.fill(0)
    tt=df5.withColumn('flag', sf.expr("case when p>0 and pr=='null' then 'N'\
                                                        when p=0 and Pr>0 then 'D'\
                                                        when p=Pr then 'R'\
                                                        else 'U' end"))
    tt.show()
```

I am getting  output like below

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
|cid|pid|   p|  Pr|flag|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|101| 14|   2|   2|   R|
|101| 10|   4|   4|   R|
|101| 11|   1|null|   U|
|101| 12|null|   1|   U|
|101| 13|   3|   3|   R|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

pyspark sqlfunction expr not working as expected.

if `p` and `pr` is same then  my `falg` will be `'R'`.

if `p` some value and `pr` is null my `flag` will be `'N'`

if `p` is null and `pr` is some value my flag is `'D'`

other case my flag is `'U'`

In this case expected output is  :

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
|cid|pid|   p|  Pr|flag|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|101| 14|   2|   2|   R|
|101| 10|   4|   4|   R|
|101| 11|   1|null|   N|
|101| 12|null|   1|   D|
|101| 13|   3|   3|   R|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isNull` and `isNotNull` *inbuilt functions* should solve your issue which can be used in query as

```
tt=df5.withColumn('flag', sf.expr("case when isNotNull(`p`) and isNull(`pr`) then 'N'\
                                                        when isNull(`p`) and isNotNull(`Pr`) then 'D'\
                                                        when p=Pr then 'R'\
                                                        else 'U' end"))
```

Thus you should get

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
|cid|pid|   p|  Pr|flag|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|101| 14|   2|   2|   R|
|101| 10|   4|   4|   R|
|101| 11|   1|null|   N|
|101| 12|null|   1|   D|
|101| 13|   3|   3|   R|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

**Note:** `na.fill(0)` is useless as it is not applied since the columns are `StringType()`

I hope the answer is helpful